# moment.js function returning NaN for date format "dddd Do MMM" in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I stumbled upon an interesting issue with moment.js in a node.js environment. Basically, I'm trying to get the time from epoch for a date format "Friday 24 Aug", but I receive NaN as a result. Here is my node.js code:

```
const moment = require("moment");
console.log(moment("Friday 24th Aug", "dddd Do MMM").valueOf());
```

```
moment.js version: 2.23.0
nodejs version: v8.11.3
OS: Linux 16.04.1-Ubuntu
```

While if I try the same console line on a browser, works fine. Has anyone stumbled upon something like this?

EDIT: Apologies for the link, I used an already created jsfiddle which had moment.js version: 2.2.1. It seems it had "worked" in that version, but now it's changed: http://jsfiddle.net/fy8w62on/ (moment.js version 2.2.1)

Comment: The linked fiddle has completely different code (`var now = moment().format('MMM DD h:mm A'); alert(now);`) from the code in the question. Unsurprisingly, if you do [the same thing in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f24noz8b/), it also results in NaN. After all, how is Moment supposed to know what year it is?

Comment: 24th August 2019 is not a Friday, but a Saturday...

Comment: ^^ and interestingly, `console.log(moment("Saturday 24th Aug", "dddd Do MMM").valueOf());` works.

Comment: Voting to close as non-repro/typo/not-useful-to-others-in-future. Back the the day, the aconym was GIGO. ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I disagree, I think it's instructive to learn that the function checks that the day of week is consistent with the date, and returns NaN when they disagree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`valueOf()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/) gives `NaN` because your moment object (`moment("Friday 24th Aug", "dddd Do MMM"`) is [invalid](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/).

Please note that, as [Default](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/defaults/) section of the docs states:

> You can create a moment object specifying only some of the units, and the rest will be defaulted to the current day, month or year, or 0 for hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds.

so moment tries to create an instance representing `2019-08-24` (using current year), but it creates an `Invalid Date` because `2019-08-24` is Saturday (using [default](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/) English US locale), not Friday (as already stated by others in the comments).

Using [`parsingFlags`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/) you will see that `weekdayMismatch` is set to `true`

```js
var m =  moment("Friday 24th Aug", "dddd Do MMM");
console.log(m.valueOf());      // NaN
console.log(m.format());       // Invalid date
console.log(m.parsingFlags()); // Object with "weekdayMismatch": true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now, the link that I was verifying it on had an older version of moment.js

Answer (score 1):

`Friday 24th Aug` does not contain a year so moment has to guess what year it is and uses the current year for the guess.

If it is 2018 at the time when you run the code then `valueOf` would not return `NaN`.

But it is 2019 so `Friday 24th Aug` of 2019 is not valid.